# Rails draper gem with Ajax/JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, draper

I'm using draper and want to use one of the decorators in a view.

With HTML everything works, but decorators don't work in the Ajax version - I get an undefined method error.

In CommentDecorator:

delegate_all

```
def comment_author
  "#{user.firstname} #{user.lastname}"
end
```

In view:

```
comment.comment_author
```

I'm using exposure, so I don't need instance variables in views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use 

`comment.decorate.comment_author`